# Zend Framework performance (autoload)

Tags: php, performance, zend-framework, autoload

I've read a lot of articles about ZF performance and still can't understand, if I've enabled byte-code caching (APC), does it make sense to use some other tricks? E.g. disabling autoload and using one big php-file with all necessary classes instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777765/using-zend-framework-for-highload-projects for some ideas.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was surprised to find that this is the only question on the site tagged performance, autoload, php.  What a better place than this to dispel the #1 autoload myth:

Modern, well-designed autoloaders won't break APC (or PHP 5.5's OPcache), and are not any worse for performance than `require_once` (except for the function call overhead, of course).

Why?  Well, now we have [`spl_autoload_register`](http://php.net/spl_autoload_register), which lets you add *multiple* autoload handlers.  This allows each third party library to ship it's own autoloader that knows how to load that library's files, and skip the rest.

For example, Zend Framework 1's [`Zend_Loader_Autoloader`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html) restricts itself to trying to load classes that start with a specific pseudo-namespace -- `Zend_` (and anything else the user asks it to load).  If it doesn't start with the desired pseudo-namespace, it simply returns and lets the next loader on the stack run.  It also knows that it can find `Zend_Foo_Bar_Baz` in `Zend/Foo/Bar/Baz.php`, so it *doesn't* need to search the include path by hand.  Like other modern framework autoloaders, it follows the the [PSR-0 autoloading standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/).

Any dependencies installed via [composer](http://getcomposer.org/) also get automatically built namespaced autoloaders in the same way.

It's that include path scouring that makes poorly-designed autoloaders suck.  You generally don't see these in modern PHP code.  The intense filesystem `stat` calls that result from trying to find files are a frequent performance drag.  Check out [this presentation by PHP creator Rasmus Lerdorf](http://talks.php.net/show/digg), in which he increases the performance of Wordpress through benchmarking, profiling, and careful removal of slow operations like `stat` calls.

The `require_once`-everything-up-front from the olden days is is *unnecessary* when you're using modern libraries and don't have a sucky autoloader.  It's only a major win when you [disable `apc.stat`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.stat) if you're using APC, or fiddling with [OPcache's `validate_`, `revalidate_`, and `enable_file_override` INI options](http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration) if you're using OPcache.

**tl;dr:** Unless you know that `stat`ting include files is *your largest bottleneck*, the Zend autoloader is just fine, and you don't need to resort to a `require_once` fest.

Comment: Thank you for such detailed answer, it's a very valuable information for me. I didn't forget about it. I've been researching for whole this time))