# How Do I Optimize Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, xdebug, optimization

I have a application built on Zend Framework I am trying to optimize.

I did some Xdebug profiling and although i cant say i understand every nitty gritty of the results i got, some things were quite obvious from the result.

For instance, the file Bootstrap.php seems to be the one gulping most of the time taking 4,553MS seconds which accounts for 92.49% of the total time.

And if i dig further, I could see that Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Boostrap->run takes the bulk of the time. Checking this out again, I found out that Zend_Controller_Front->Dispatch might actually be the function inside the Boostrap.php that takes time to execute.

Question is, from these indices that i have, how best can I go about Optimizing the application? If it caching, how do i go about applying Caching to this situation?

Thanks

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777765/using-zend-framework-for-highload-projects

Comment: 4.5 secs is a very long time for a Bootstrap. What does your bootstrap do?

Comment: @tim fountain Basically not that much...I have 5 modules and each of these modules have their bootstrap. And right now, its just blank (Might be adding stuff to them as the need arises) and it is only that sets a value in Zend_Registry. So wondering why it takes that long :|

Comment: If you've done some profiling can you stick the callgrind file up somewhere so we an download it and take a look?

Comment: http://bit.ly/AAWNPm for the login in session. This requires authentication via Linkedin, so this might explain some of the time lag, this http://bit.ly/AAD1Kh is for just a normal page request. Thanks @Tim Fountain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the look of the callgrinds, on the login page the app is spending most of it's time in curl_exec, which is to be expected if you're doing a remote login. But it is doing 10 separate curl_execs which seems excessive. I'm not familiar with the LinkedIn login auth, but is it possible your app is running the remote login code multiple times?

On the standard page request the app is spending most of its time connecting to MySQL, and it seems to be doing this twice. Are you using a remote DB server, and do you need two separate DB connections?

Assuming you are using a remote DB server and it is on the same network as your web server, there seems to be some networking issue there. I'd check the latency to that server if you can, and try connecting to the IP address instead of a hostname to see if that makes any difference (if doing this is much faster this would suggest an issue with the DNS setup on your web server).

Comment: Thanks @Tim Fountain...you pointers are really useful...Would look into those part of the system.