# Zend Framework optimization -> "preload everything"?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've searched for some tips how to optimize ZF's performance, and I found a good list here:
[Using Zend Framework for highload projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777765/using-zend-framework-for-highload-projects)
(you can see the accepted answer by David Weinraub)

What I dont understand there is the 4.point: *"Preload everything (Symfony 2 Preview does!)..."*

What does it mean to "preload everything"?
You can of course write some other tips if you have more, (or if the above answers are not fully satisfactory..)

Thanks for your time. And sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I feel like I am writing this often. Did you try profiling your application first to see if there are not any obvious bottlenecks? Having APC (and well configured with enough memory to hold what you need) is a must. After that, you can waste a lot of time optimizing things that do not matter based on opinions on the web. Nothing beats a profiler to figure out what is wrong with your code.

Comment: When you profile the code of a PHP framework like ZF, you see that there is a lot of calls, a lot of classes loaded. It doesn't help you to make it faster. There is not one or two big bottlenecks that would be easy to remove. The only thing you can do is cache, cache and cache again. Preloading, APC are cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preloading means taking the classes used in almost every request (like Bootstrap, Zend_Config, Zend_Registry, Zend_Db, ... depending on your project) and putting them all in one file you load at first instead of doing lazy loading (loading only when needed).

As Zend does not do it by itself, it can be rough when you want to update it.  I would try the following before editing Zend's code:

There is the performance guide from Zend: 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/performance.html

To help speedup your application, you should consider using APC :
http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php

Finally, you could cache computed results with Memcached:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php

Speeding up your application must be done on multiple levels to be the most efficient.